# How do I download a image from a url with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

Can anyone help me with the below code, I'm trying just to download the image from the below url using Python. I looked online and got the below code but it giving me the below error on the urllib request?

```
import urllib.request 
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('c://CSALE//chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://kbdevstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/asset-blobs/19950_en_1')
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/img').get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, "wolf.png")
driver.close()
```

Error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

Comment: A workaround for this , is to use driver.save_screenshot which works but there are black sides below and to the side which isn't ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the below with request module :

```
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/img').get_attribute('src')

data = requests.get(img).content
local_filename = 'Dog_with_Selenium.jpg'

with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
  f.write(data)
```

Comment: just tried that but still getting an error Max retries exceeded with url: /asset-blobs/19950_en_1 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020066EB06D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')) - not sure if its the code or what the issue is

Comment: This is not the relevant error for this code, I got the output as expected. try again.

Comment: your code is working as expected when not connected to the work proxy. I actually checked my original code and it is also working.... I guess the question is what is faster urllib or requests. thanks for posting